# Why am I getting YAML files instead of weight files when using ISR library in Python and TensorFlow for deep learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, interrupt, h5py

My code is creating the weights and logs folders but not generating the actual weight files.
log_dirs = {'logs': './logs36', 'weights': './weights36'}
This line does creates logs and weights folder, but instead of getting .h5py or any other binary formatted weight file, I get YAML file which I think supposed to give us information parameters of the architecture or something like that. I'm very new to DL specially ISR library that's why I couldn't figure it out on my own.

My goal is here to get high resolution images from low resolutions images, so maybe is it possible that when I defined hyperparameters of the models (rdn, f_ext and disc) I'm doing something wrong?
P.S: Those values are defaults, I didn't change anything [as it can be seen from here](https://github.com/idealo/image-super-resolution/tree/master#pre-trained-networks)

My code for you guys to review.

`

```
from ISR.models import RDN, Discriminator
from ISR.models import Cut_VGG19
from ISR.train import Trainer


# Define paths for HR (220 x 220) and LR (22 x 22) input JPG

lr_train_dir = r"C:\data\ds\resized_sentinel_jpg_2016_lr"
hr_train_dir = r"C:\data\ds\naip_jpg_2016_hr"
lr_valid_dir = r"C:\data\ds\resized_sentinel_jpg_2016_lr"
hr_valid_dir = r"C:\data\ds\naip_jpg_2016_hr"
 



lr_train_patch_size = 22
layers_to_extract = [5, 9]
scale = 10
hr_train_patch_size = lr_train_patch_size * scale

rdn  = RDN(arch_params={'C':4, 'D':3, 'G':64, 'G0':64, 'T':10, 'x':scale}, patch_size=lr_train_patch_size)
f_ext = Cut_VGG19(patch_size=hr_train_patch_size, layers_to_extract=layers_to_extract)
discr = Discriminator(patch_size=hr_train_patch_size, kernel_size=3)


loss_weights = {
  'generator': 0.0,
  'feature_extractor': 0.0833,
  'discriminator': 0.01
}
losses = {
  'generator': 'mae',
  'feature_extractor': 'mse',
  'discriminator': 'binary_crossentropy'
} 

log_dirs = {'logs': './logs36', 'weights': './weights36'}

learning_rate = {'initial_value': 0.0004, 'decay_factor': 0.5, 'decay_frequency': 30}

flatness = {'min': 0.0, 'max': 0.15, 'increase': 0.01, 'increase_frequency': 5}

trainer = Trainer(
    generator=rdn,
    discriminator=discr,
    feature_extractor=f_ext,
    lr_train_dir=lr_train_dir,
    hr_train_dir=hr_train_dir,
    lr_valid_dir=lr_valid_dir,
    hr_valid_dir=hr_valid_dir,
    loss_weights=loss_weights,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    flatness=flatness,
    dataname='div2k',
    log_dirs=log_dirs,
    weights_generator=None,
    weights_discriminator=None,
    n_validation=40,
)  


trainer.train(
    epochs=36,
    steps_per_epoch=25,
    batch_size=2,
    monitored_metrics={'val_PSNR_Y': 'max'}
)
```

First picture shows the YAML file and the other is what I'm trying to get.

[image][image]What I'm getting vs What I'm expecting